# Access denied (5) for net user /domain command

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, active-directory, windows-domain

I would like to get some help debugging an issue we are experiencing in a specific server.

We have a web application that uses windows accounts to validate user credentials and groups. We noticed that when we deployed to a specific server, we were not able to validate any accounts other than the account the process is running under. The error reported is Access denied (5).

To debug, we tried to use net user /domain in order to see if it is a lower-level issue. We got the same error Access denied (5).

When we validate the same account the process is running as, i.e. if the process was running under the "admin" account we would do net user admin /domain, it would work.

Both the application and the cmd command we ran was run with Administrator access

I came accross [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/535130/net-user-domain-returning-error-5-access-is-denied?answertab=votes#tab-top) article and tried to debug the same way. Our wireshark logs did not show the same errors. Both OpenDomain requests had successful responses.

We also went to the AD and added read access to "Authenticated Users" for the Builtin and Users directory.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.